# C# не отправляется запрос по HttpClient

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, gtk

Имеется класс с методом для отправки запроса по HttpClient. Этот метод правильно работает, когда я использую его в консольном приложении, но при при вызове из обработчика события нажатия кнопки в GTK он просто выполняется бесконечно долго. Отладка показала, что стопорится всё именно на строчке, где посылается запрос.

Код обработчика события:

```
private void Auth_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            var data = VKAPI.UserAuthAsync(text_Login.Text.Trim(), text_Pass.Text.Trim()).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(data.user_id + " " + data.access_token);
        }
```

Код Класса:

```
public static class VKAPI
{
    public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public static AuthData UserAuthData { get; private set; }
    public const int client_id = 2274003;

    public static async Task<AuthData> UserAuthAsync(string login, string pass)
    {
        string data = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id={client_id}&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username={login}&password={pass}");
        dynamic json = JObject.Parse(data);

        UserAuthData = new AuthData((string)json.access_token, (int)json.user_id);

        return UserAuthData;
    }
}

public class AuthData
{
    public readonly string access_token;
    public readonly int user_id;
    public AuthData(string access_token, int user_id)
    {
        this.access_token = access_token;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
}
```

Даже не представляю, с чем может быть связано такое поведение. Грешил, что может с полей с логином и паролем неправильно считываются значения, но даже если захардкодить нужные строки при вызове метода, результат один.

UPD:
В этом приложении запрос отправляется, если разместить вызов метода в точке входа программы (main), но не работает ни в одном методе обработчиков события окна.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества, в чём проблема с отправкой запросов по HttpClient в приложении на GTK_Sharp?

Comment: Ну, как минимум, `var data = VKAPI.UserAuthAsync` -> `var data = await VKAPI.UserAuthAsync`, а `void Auth_Clicked` -> `void async Auth_Clicked`

Comment: Ну да, асинхронные методы нужно правильно вызывать, через `await`, скорее всего в этом дело. Сейчас просто управление нормально в GUI не возвращается.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Большое спасибо, помогло

Comment: Вот вам и `var`, поленились посмотреть возвращаемый тип - получили непредсказуемое поведение. Первым делом, если код не работает, проставьте явные типы, тогда почти наверняка сможете найти ошибку самостоятельно.

Comment: @aepot, проблема была не в этом. Возвращаемый тип я и так знал, и этот же код работал в обычном консольном приложении. Сделал обработчик события нажатия кнопки асинхронным и всё заработало. Это странно, ведь в консольном приложении метод Main() был не асинхронным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло сделать обработчик события нажатия на кнопку асинхронным